# Passing and getting data from class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have 2 forms, `form1` and `form2`. In form1 I call form2, where I input 2 numbers, one for height and for width of a picturebox. Then I want to pass that data from `form2` to `form1`, where I create picturebox with said size.
Then I want to store height and width to class and then access that info from `form1`.
Here is my code:

Form1

```
namespace NPA_projekt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form2 f2 = new Form2();

        image img = new image();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbMainArea.Width = img.width;
            pbMainArea.Height = img.length;
        }
    }

}
```

Form2

```
    namespace NPA_projekt
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        image img = new image();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //reset btn
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nudWidth.Value = 640;
            nudLength.Value = 400;
        }

        //cancel btn
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //ok btn
        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            img.width = Convert.ToInt32(nudWidth.Value);
            img.length = Convert.ToInt32(nudLength.Value);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Class image

```
namespace NPA_projekt
{
    class image
    {
        public int width = 0;
        public int length = 0;
    }
}
```

Values, that are stored in `form2`, are set to their original values, when I want to use them in `form1`. Could someone please elaborate what's happening.
Thank you all!

Comment: Expose the `img` as a property of the Form2, e.g., `public image Img{get; private set;}` and then in Form1 after the `f2.ShowDialog();` call, get the `img` instance through `image img = f2.Img;`

Answer (score 0):

`img` is declared twice.  Once in `Form1` and again in `Form2`. When you are setting the width and height of `img` in `Form2` you are setting it for the image instance you declared in `Form2` not `Form1`.  You need to make the `img` in `Form1` visible to `Form2` and perform the operation on that.

So, make `img` in `Form1` public:

```
    public image img {get; set;}
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        img = new image();
    }
```

Then you need to access it in `Form2` (one way should be the `Parent` property of the form):

```
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = (Form1)this.Parent
        form1.img.width = Convert.ToInt32(nudWidth.Value);
        form1.img.length = Convert.ToInt32(nudLength.Value);
        this.Close();
    }
```

I haven't tested this all out, but the approach is valid.  The key to eliminating the confusion is getting rid of the `img` declaration in `Form2` and realizing that you need to get access to `Form1` from `Form2`

Comment: Your code gives me this error: Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'image' is less accessible than property 'Form2.img'

Comment: Sounds like your `image` type declaration is restricted.  Try making it public a la `public class image {....`  Also, why do you have a `Form2.img` property?  That is the one you need to remove.

Comment: I set it to `public class iamge {....}` and it doesn't give me this error now. But now when I want to set some value from numericupdown to width and length (in image class) I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I did research the meaning of it, but I have no clue how to fix it. Also, thank your for your help!

Comment: That is one of the most general of exceptions and it means that you are trying to access a field on something that is null.  You should try setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the `btnOK_Click` method and seeing what the values for everything are.  Something in there is null that you aren't expecting to be.  I would bet that nudWidth, and probably nudLength, are null.  You will have to look into why whatever is null isn't getting set properly.  And no problem!

Comment: The problem is definitely setting any value to `form1.img.width` or `form1.img.length`, not just value from numericUpDown, but any integer. It throws the exception.